# Make two divs stick together when resizing the browser

Tags: css

I'm working on a template page for a website.
It can be seen here : http://www.acielouvert.net/clos/

In the header, I have a slideshow with images width of 100%, they resize with the browser.

When I resize the browser below `960px` I want div `.continue` to stay in touch with `div.header`.
Actually I put a `margin-top: 700px` on div `.continue`.

Have you any idea how can I do this ?
I don't want to use media queries.

Please see here the code for the page : http://pastebin.com/gLaerw1F
Thanks,
Guillaume

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the post, and read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use media queries?  They're designed exactly for this scenario...

Comment: You think I have to go with media queries. I would have to set a lot of scenarios for the divs to be always touching each others.

Comment: I don't think you can do this will CSS. You have to use Javascript to react to the resizing of the page and adjust .continue to have a margin top equal to the size of the DIV containing the photos.

Comment: Ok, I will ask for help with javascript

Comment: No need of javascript. Just need css media quries to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
   // What ever you want ...
}
```

Comment: If I do so, ".continue" will reach the top of the page. I can set some steps with different width and margin-top, but user will see that between the steps .continue will not touch .header.

Comment: What actually you want ??

Comment: I want .continue to be always touching the bottom of .header

Comment: try resizing the page below 960px, you'll see the space between .continue and .header. I want to get rid of this space.

Comment: Make the `position: relative;` of .container to the header and then give height ... got it ?

Comment: I try giving .container-header a position relative with an height of 700px, but it's not working. So I try to give a max-height of 700px, not working either.

Answer (score 0):

I did some several test and the only way I found is using % for the `margin-top` of `.continue`
When user resize the browser below 960px, the two divs are stuck together and I avoid the gap due to `margin-top: 700px;`
I will surely add some `media queries` in the end but the % is helping a lot.
Thanks for your help @Junaid, @Josh Burgess, @jurgemaister.